# Module '"react-icon-cloud"' has no exported member 'renderImg'

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I used to use renderImg in react-icon-cloud version 3.0.3 in next js, but now I can not import renderImg in version 4.0.0. There is an error:

```
Module '"react-icon-cloud"' has no exported member 'renderImg'.ts(2305)
```

here is a code where I use renderImg:

```
  const ImgATag = data.map((item: any) =>
    renderImg({
      imgProps: {
        src: imgLink + item.logo,
        alt: item.title,
        width: 700,
        height: 700,
      },
      aProps: {
        href: `#${item.title}`,
      },
    })
  );
```

Comment: The `renderImg` function has been removed in v4.0.0.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, how do I render the image then?